# Title of a children's book about a young Pegasus who fall from heaven and ends up working in a Circus on a high wire, from the 1950's I think

Tags: story-identification, magic, childrens-novel

Book from the 1960's or '50s. A picture book with bright bold illustrations.
An image of baby Pegasus in a cloud field in the sky with its mother and other winged horses. It fall through a gap in the clouds to Earth where it ends up in a circus on a high wire act until he learns to fly when he falls off the be wire and goes home.

I've searched in old book shops and online, but never found it.

Comment: And it looks like the reference at solveforum.com is data-mining in an effort to grab advertising revenue.